# Unused argument in layer_

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap, lattice, levelplot

I am trying to reproduce the following here:

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/201-levelplot-with-latticeextra.html

```
# library
library(latticeExtra) 
 
# create data
set.seed(1) 
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)) 
data$z <- with(data, x * y + rnorm(100, sd = 1)) 
 
# showing data points on the same color scale 
levelplot(z ~ x * y, data, 
          panel = panel.levelplot.points, cex = 1.2
    ) + 
    layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 200))
```

But I am getting

> Error in layer(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 200), under = TRUE) :
> unused argument (under = TRUE)

This was working fine yesterday, I am not sure what happened?

Comment: My guess is that sincenyesterday you have loaded ggplot2, which has a function called `layer` too. Restart your R session and run the above code again. It should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loaded another package that has a function called `layer`, it will mask this function in `latticeExtra`. There are [numerous packages](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=layer) with a `layer` function.

You can either restart your R session as suggested by Allan and only load the package(s) you need. Or, you can tell R which `layer` function you want:

```
levelplot(z ~ x * y, data, 
          panel = panel.levelplot.points, cex = 1.2
         ) + 
  latticeExtra::layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 200))
```